# Need advice on checking a array for changes

Tags: php, compare, md5

I'm working on a project which saves information into a database from an external API. This API only shows the latest available information, so I need to check this API and compare it with my own database info to see if there are new changes.

Before, I did this by comparing every single value manually:

```
if($externalapi['item'] !== $mydatabase['item']) {
    // changes detected!
}
```

Now that I'm making a V2 of this project, I feel like this is not the correct approach and I should do it differently.

I've thought about MD5'ing the external API output, and my own database output, and compare these two.

```
if(md5($externalapi) !== md5($mydatabase)) {
    // changes detected!
}
```

but I'm not sure how reliable that is.

What would be the best approach to this?

Comment: I recommend not to use this function if you are more concerned about data security. As you can have a look here [php.net md5](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php)

Comment: Unless your data structure is very complex, a simple loop to compare the values for all the keys offers you a 100% accurate solution, and should be fast enough for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

When determining the reliability of a hash function for this sort of use, you would be interested in the 'birthday problem' name-collision probability for cryptographic hash. For example I believe a typical MD5 hash will have a 50% chance of producing a name collision if you hash several billion different lists every second over the course of 100 years.

Searching for 'birthday problem' or 'name-collision' probability for cryptographic hashes will give you all the math you could want for understanding the reliability.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Cody. So MD5 is probably not reliable enough for this job. What could be reliable approach for checking an array for changes?

Comment: In my opinion MD5 is a fast hash that has a sufficient output range to deal with this sort of problem. If the event of a failure is so worrisome and you like to overkill your problems, then you can always use a a hash with a larger output like sha-512 which will likely not have any collisions while humanity still exists.